# WMS View/Lib for Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, wms

We need a graphical component (view) for rendering maps from any WMS services for Android andn iOS. My researches only show that there is basically only the Google Maps API available as Android/iOS library (MapView).

Before programming a WMS view lib by ourselves, are there any (free or licensed) WMS view libraries for those OSses available, which can be used in own apps? We tried using OpenLayers in a WebView, which is not really satisfying from a performance point of view.

thanks for your help

Comment: Check this link...http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/

Answer (score 2):

I think this will fit your requirements:
https://confluence.prodevelop.es/display/GVMN/Home

From their homepage:

> gvSIG Mini is a free viewer of free access maps based on tiles
>   (OpenStreetMap, YahooMaps, Microsoft Bing, ...), with a WMS, WMS-C
>   client, address and POI search, routes, hybrid location and many more
>   things. It runs with both on/off-line modes.

While it is packaged as an application rather than a library, the source is available (GPL) so you should be able to extract what you need:

- https://confluence.prodevelop.es/display/GVMN/Android+Download
- https://svn.prodevelop.es/public/gvsigmini/

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using Osmdroid API for this, but still without success. This requires modifying several java classes as XYTileSource and BitmapTileSourceBase.

- [osmdroid - OpenStreetMap-Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

There are applications in the Android Market that can make this work perfectly as OruxMaps but not have an API for development. : (

Answer (score 2):

[Nutiteq SDK](http://developer.nutiteq.com/) can do this. WMS sample works with EPSG:4326, but SDK supports also other projections and you can modify the map class to use those.  Disclaimer: I'm the developer of it.

Update in 2016: updated links, removed obsolete 3 year old references

Comment: yes, this was 3.5 year old link. Nutiteq SDK is now in http://developer.nutiteq.com

Answer (score 0):

Look at [OpenStreetMap](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=openstreetmap&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.openstreetmap.org/&ei=OYzYTpPBC5G3hAe_teGwDg&usg=AFQjCNE391PIxJggzIKZvinNWNpOh7nqqw). It provides maps for both iOS and Android

1. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS
2. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

Api - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Hope, this helps you.

Comment: But doesn't it limit the map services to OpenStreetmap services? What I need is an OGC conform WMS lib.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the openlayers client. Yes I know it's a Web Client but you can use it in your WebView.

http://openlayers.org/

https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch10-openlayers-goes-mobile/example-01.html

I have a few apps with openlayers maps. Some of these uses online map servers and some uses tiles stored inside the app (offline maps).

For interactions with webView, we use JavaScriptInjections